# Moving symbols in Print layout, not in Main Window

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing

I am working on production of Fire Evacuation maps. There are three assets, Fire Indicator Panel, Fire Mimic Panel and Emergency Exit that are located one very close to the other on a wall. They are all styled with SVG.

When I create a print layout the symbols overlap with each other (see picture below):

[image: Print Layout]

Is it possible to move the symbols in Print Layout so they look neatly one next to the other in a row (or one below the other in a column), without affecting the actual location of these assets?

I am running QGIS Noosa on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: Have a look at the point displacement symbol option. It automatically displaces point symbols when two points are near each other (you choose how far apart is "near"). By default it adds a central point and a circle or grid lines connecting the symbols, but you can get rid of these by making them transparent.

Answer (score 2):

If the symbols are located in separate layers, you can use `Draw effects` located under `Layer properties -> Symbology -> SVG marker -> Draw effects` as in shown below:

[image]

Click on the star and select Transform from the drop-down menu:

[image]

Under `Translate X, Y`, you can change the values to move the symbols in the directions you like. This will affect only symbols and will not change the location of the original points. However, it will not work if all points are located in the same layer because using this draw effect option, all the points will be moved together, and thus, it will not solve the problem.

One possible way if you have such case is to duplicate the layer in the table of contents and use Build query to show only the points of interest based on each category and then use `Draw effects` to move the points separately.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of Translate X,Y. However, it affects all records in the same layer. Maybe I have to try to create a copy of the layer and play with that one instead.